# Do we say "Bob is my second big brother"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

A couple has these sons and daughters:

- Tom (a male - born 1st)
- Mary (a female - born 2nd)
- Lana (a female - born 3rd)
- Bob (a male - born 4th)
- Lulu (a female - born 5th)
- Mike (a male - born 6th)
- Suri (a female - born 7th)

Is it correct for Suri to say:

> "**Tom is my biggest brother, Bob is my second big brother and Mike is my third big brother**"?

Is it correct for Lana to say:

> "**Bob is my 1st little brother, and Mike is my second little brother**"?

Comment: "Big/little brother/sister" are sometimes used informally, especially if there is a substantial age gap, but I think It would be more usual for Suri to say something like "Tom is my eldest brother, Bob is my second eldest brother, and Mike is the brother next in age to me."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question form of "he is the 6th son of his parents"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267457/question-form-of-he-is-the-6th-son-of-his-parents) The question is phrased somewhat differently, but my answer details why this kind of question doesn't really work for english speakers.

Comment: @JavaLatte, the answer didn't say clearly "the second eldest brother" or "the second elder brother" and other info that I need.

Comment: @Tom As the linked answer explains, most native English speakers don't think in these terms, and I would discuss this matter with caution because 1) for the most part, the order of children is unimportant in British and American families 2) it's sexist to regard brothers and sisters differently 3) British families tend tend to be small- on average 1.7 children 4) 16% of british children have step-siblings, and so conventional enumeration doesn't work. Eldest works in Kate's example, but elder does not. Eldest means oldest, (first) but Elder applies equally to all of the older children.

Comment: @JavaLatte, at least you should say that first in your comment. In Vietnamese, we say "first/2nd/third brother", so I thought English should have similar things

Comment: @Tom yes, it's a cultural rather than a linguistic issue. It would be a linguistic issue too in Indonesian, where there is no specific word for brother and sister.- You have to say "male sibling" or "female sibling".

Comment: In AmE, birth order can be important -- just ask anyone with brothers and sisters. The oldest usually has more of the responsibility than the others. To refer to all siblings, a list is usually enough in order by age. Otherwise, "oldest", "second oldest", "third oldest", and so on. Sometimes people cut the list in half by using "middle" for the middle child, and then "second youngest", and so on until the youngest child.